# JavaFX, Editable DatePicker is not adding seperator in date

Tags: javafx

I want working with DatePicker. And I want that, editable DatePicker should add separator symbols like / and - itself. Can I do it with any method or attribute in SceneBuilder fxml file.

[Here is the Image of my UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KWTv.png)

[And I want DatePicker should work like this Automatically](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jlcwr.png)

Comment: When should the `DatePicker` be adding the separators itself? When the user hits enter? While the user is typing?

Comment: Preferably while entering

Comment: I'm not sure about the particulars (hence no answer) but you can use a [`TextFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/TextFormatter.html) on the [editor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/DatePicker.html#editorProperty) of the `DatePicker`.

Comment: DatePicker has a converter property ... depending on what exactly you want to achieve it might help.